# OneToOne relationship with Ebeans in Play Framework 2.3.8

Tags: playframework, yaml, playframework-2.3, ebean

Forgive me if this is trivial - I am a C#/.NET backend engineer by day and am new to Play Framework and EBean, and all the other things that go along with this environment.

I am using the in memory H2 database and javax.persistence library to manage my business layer/persistence layer.  I have three entities (Course, Student, Transcript) that I have defined and am attempting to seed by using a yaml file with initial data.

So far, I have managed to create, persist, and retrieve a ManyToMany relationship between Course and Student.

However, I am having trouble creating a OneToOne relationship between Student and Transcript.  After seeding the db with initial data, I try to retrieve either Student or Transcript objects via a find e.g.

```
FIND.where().eq(ID, id).findUnique()
```

the reference to the other object is null (Transcript object has a null reference for it's Student property, Student object has a null reference for it's Transcript property).

It does appear that the Student has a reference to the Transcript when I save to the database though (see the Global.java below), just when stepping through with the debugger and inspecting the properties.

Here is the Student entity (note the @OneToOne transcript property):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="students")
public class Student extends Model {

    private static final String ID = "id";

    @Id
    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    public String id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String username;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String password;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String fullname;

    @Constraints.Required
    @ManyToMany
    public List<Course> coursesPreferred = new ArrayList<Course>();

    @Constraints.Required
    public int numCoursesPreferred;

    @Constraints.Required
    @OneToOne
    public Transcript transcript;

    // -- Queries

    private static final Model.Finder<String, Student> FIND =
            new Model.Finder<>(String.class, Student.class);

    /**
     * Returns all students.
     */
    public static List<Student> findAll() {
        return FIND.all();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the student with the given ID.
     *
     * @param id student ID
     */
    public static Student findById(String id) {

        return FIND.where().eq(ID, id).findUnique();
    }

    // --

    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" + fullname + "}";
    }

}
```

and here is the Transcript entity (note the @OneToOne Student property, mapped by transcript):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="transcripts")
public class Transcript extends Model {

    private static final String ID = "id";

    @Id
    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    public String id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="transcript")
    public Student student;

    @Constraints.Required
    public int creditsEarned;

    // -- Queries

    private static final Model.Finder<String, Transcript> FIND =
            new Model.Finder<>(String.class, Transcript.class);

    /**
     * Returns all transcripts.
     */
    public static List<Transcript> findAll() {
        return FIND.all();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the transcript with the given ID.
     *
     * @param id transcript ID
     */
    public static Transcript findById(String id) {
        return FIND.where().eq(ID, id).findUnique();
    }

    // --

   public String toString() {
        return "Transcript{" + id + "}";
    }

}
```

Here is the yaml file with the initial data:

```
# Courses

courses:

    - &course6476 !!models.Course
        id:         6476
        tag:        "CS 6476"
        name:       "Computer Vision"
        abbrev:     "CV"
        core:       Yes

    - &course6035 !!models.Course
        id:         6035
        tag:        "CS 6035"
        name:       "Introduction to Information Security"
        abbrev:     "IIS"
        core:       No

    - &course6210 !!models.Course
        id:         6210
        tag:        "CS 6210"
        name:       "Advanced Operating Systems"
        abbrev:     "AOS"
        core:       Yes

# Transcripts

transcripts:

    - &transcript0001 !!models.Transcript
        id:         0001
        creditsEarned: 42

# Students

students:

    - &student0001 !!models.Student
        id:         0001
        username:   "joeschmoe"
        password:   "password1234"
        fullname:   "Joe Schmoe"
        numCoursesPreferred: 2
        coursesPreferred:
            - *course6210
            - *course6035
        transcript: *transcript0001
```

and lastly, here is the Global.java file where the data is read in and saved:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    private static final String INITIAL_DATA_FILE = "initial-data.yml";
    private static final String COURSES = "courses";
    private static final String STUDENTS = "students";
    private static final String TRANSCRIPTS = "transcripts";

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
        InitialData.insert(app);
    }

    private static class InitialData {
        private static void insert(Application app) {
            if (Student.findAll().size() == 0) {
                Map<String, List<?>> all =
                        (Map<String, List<?>>)     Yaml.load(INITIAL_DATA_FILE);

                Ebean.save(all.get(COURSES));
                Ebean.save(all.get(TRANSCRIPTS));
                Ebean.save(all.get(STUDENTS));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I might be missing here?  Do I need to change the way I am specifying the OneToOne relationship?  Additional steps to debug/troubleshoot?  Any information whatsoever is appreciated, as I have hit a brick wall.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: What you're missing? You're missing understanding what you're using. You use EBean. EBean != JPA. EBean != Hibernate. They are totally different. So suggest that you edit your question and remove JPA, Hibernate references and focus it to EBean only

Comment: Thanks Neil, I've removed the references to JPA and Hibernate so the discussion can focus on EBean and Play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  The query that was failing to retrieve the OneToOne property values was:

```
FIND.where().eq(ID, id).findUnique();
```

So for instance, this would return a Student with a valid Transcript reference for the Student.transcript property, but all the properties on that Transcript reference were either null or default e.g. creditsEarned = 0 instead of 42 like it should have been based on my seed data.

It appears that in order to retrieve the missing values you must explicitly "fetch" them in the query.  So for a Student query by ID it became:

```
FIND.fetch("transcript").where().eq(ID, id).findUnique();
```

This returns the fully populated Student, including all of the Transcript values.  I read that setting @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) should do this automatically, but I found in a few sources that EBeans doesn't honor the fetch parameter for @OneToOne.